# Control number of items on sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 2 ul, one draggable and another is sortable, Sortable has a max-height and Draggable's item has it's height.

I  only want to add an item when the total height is <= max-height of sortable, but still sortable (dont disable it).

Check this example here:

http://jsbin.com/asIveBo/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

**Update**

```
var reject = false;
var received = false;

$('#tu').sortable({
  connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
  update: function( event, ui ) {
    if(reject && received)
      ui.item.remove();
    if($('ul#tu').height()+'px' == $('ul#tu').css('max-height'))
      reject = true;
    received = false;
  },
  receive: function( event, ui ){
    received = true;  
  }
});
$('#ke li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: $('#tu')
});
```